# How can I AutoIncrement a document id in Nodejs for Couchbase

Tags: node.js, couchbase

My code :

```
bucket.insert("docid", jsonVersion, function (err, response) {   
    if (err) {
        console.log('Failed to save to Couchbase', err);      
        return;  
    } else {
        res.send('Saved to Couchbase!');
    }
});
```

How can I increment doc id automatically when i take data from web form.

I am using Nodejs and Couchbase.

Comment: http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.1/documents-atomic.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't have AutoIncrement in Couchbase.
What you do have are [Counters](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/core-operations.html). 
With counters you can increment a number in an atomic matter and then assign or concat it to your docId.

Something like:

```
bucket.counter(counterKey, 1, {initial: 0}, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // insert code here
    console.log('Incremented Counter:', res.value);

    console.log('Example Successful - Exiting');
    process.exit(0);
  });
```

for more example please look here:
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/tree/master/nodejs